# jquery toggle not clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have implimented a Jquery hide/show toggle that is supposed to effect the menu and submenu. The code works, but for some reason it is not successful within the context of my broader site code. I cannot seem to figure out what the problem is. Any suggestions?
http://studiopowell.net/TEST_gradient.html

JQuery:

```
    $('.menu').click(function(e){
    $(this).find('.submenu').fadeToggle();
});
$('.submenu').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

html:

```
   <div id="gradient"> 


<div id="contain">
<div class="titles"></div></div>
<div class="menu">W o r k<div class="submenu">I m a g e</div></div>

  <div id="menu3"><a href="http://studiopowell.net" target="_blank">I n f o</a></div>

</div>
```

css:

```
#contain{
     padding-top: -10px;
     display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
     -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -moz-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-align-content: center;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
    align-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
   position: relative;
     -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
 }



 .titles {
    font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color:#33;
    text-align:left;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: 50px;
     display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -moz-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -webkit-box-pack: start;
    -moz-box-pack: start;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-pack: start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    -webkit-align-content: center;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
    align-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;


}

.submenu {
    font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue";
    font-style:underline;
    font-size: 12px;
    color:#333;
    opacity:0.3;
    text-align:left;
    padding-left: 100px;
    padding-top: -100px;
    margin-top: -14px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
     display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -moz-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-align-content: center;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
    align-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 8000;
}

.menu {
    font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue";
    font-style:underline;
    font-size: 12px;
    color:#333;
    opacity:0.4;
    text-align:left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: -100px;
    margin-top: -298px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;

    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -moz-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -webkit-box-pack: start;
    -moz-box-pack: start;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-pack: start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    -webkit-align-content: center;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
    align-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: start;
    -moz-box-align: start;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-align: start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    position:relative;
    z-index: 8040;

    }


#menu3 {
    font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue";
    font-style:underline;
    font-size: 12px;
    color:#333;
    opacity:0.4;
    text-align:left;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: -100px;
    margin-top: -114px;
    margin-left:50%;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -moz-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -webkit-box-pack: end;
    -moz-box-pack: end;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
    -ms-flex-pack: end;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    -webkit-align-content: center;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
    align-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: start;
    -moz-box-align: start;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-align: start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    position:relative;
    z-index:9900;


}
```

Comment: Where is the jQuery code?. You can use the stack snippet to replicate the problem.

Comment: Please include all *relevant* code (that doesn't mean *all* code) from links that you use in your question. From your site source, you're including jQuery twice. Don't do that. Pick one.

Comment: Every JQuery I have tried doesn't work, so I was hoping for suggestions as to what that JQuery might look like. Any JQuery I have tried has no effect, aka, no show/hide effect. There is no "problem" per say, as nothing happens.

Comment: @ajp15243 Sorry I am a novice. What exactly do you mean? I have pasted only the code from the relevant divs... Thanks for your help!

Comment: I believe he means the relevant jQuery that you attempted that did not work.

Comment: In other words, where's the code you say doesn't work?

Comment: Oh, my. sorry! Question has been amended to include one of my attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using classes that make more sense, like this...

```
<div class="menu">
    Menu
    <div class="submenu">Sub-Menu</div>
</div>
```

Then your jQuery is simply...

```
$('.menu').click(function(e){
    $(this).find('.submenu').fadeToggle();
});

// If you don't want your sub-menu to trigger the toggle, add this:
$('.submenu').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: I simplied and applied the new JQuery but still no functionality on the site! Any thoughts as to what may still be wrong?

Comment: I updated to add some code to prevent the submenu from triggering the menu toggle. Here's a jsfiddle to show that it works: http://jsfiddle.net/4w33uvot/ ... If you're still having issues the problem may be elsewhere in your site.

Comment: Thanks @Luke, the code looks like it works great, and I appreciate the help a ton! It looks like my problem might be layering, as while the code works, i cant seem to get it to actively perform on my site. but the z-index's all line up so I am stumped.